# Check if a folder doesn't exist in c# using FileSystemInfo

Tags: c#

I am new with c# and *I am trying to find a folder that can contain a string*, for example:

Name: 92011

So the folder can be:

- Jason Mohoa 92011
- 92011
- 92011_newOne

and so on...

And I am doing it with this code and works fine:

```
string ped = datagridview1.SelectedCells[0].Value.ToString();
string path = @"C:\";
DirectoryInfo hdDirectoryInWhichToSearch = new DirectoryInfo(path);
FileSystemInfo[] filesAndDirs = hdDirectoryInWhichToSearch.GetFileSystemInfos("*" + ped + "*");
string fullName = "";
foreach (FileSystemInfo foundFile in filesAndDirs)
{
    fullName = foundFile.FullName + @"\";
    Process.Start(fullName);
}
```

The problem is that if FileSystemInfo finds a folder, it will open it, but if it can't find it, it does nothing and I would like it to say, for example, a message with "The folder does not exist".

**How can I check if a folder is not found in this foreach?**

Comment: `var noneFound = filesAndDirs.Length == 0`

Answer (score 1):

You could use `System.Linq`:

```
bool foundAny = filesAndDirs.Any(); 
foreach (FileSystemInfo foundFile in filesAndDirs)
{
    fullName = foundFile.FullName + @"\";
    Process.Start(fullName);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since `filesAndDirs` is an array, you can use its `Length` property to determine whether or not it's empty.

```
foreach (FileSystemInfo foundFile in filesAndDirs)
{
    fullName = foundFile.FullName + @"\";
    Process.Start(fullName);
}
if (filesAndDirs.Length == 0)
{
    // Nothing was found
}
```